# Firefox OS privileged app won't load to WebIDE

Tags: firefox, firefox-os

I have an application I developed for Firefox OS. Whole app is available on github:

[kursrs](https://github.com/ivandejanovic/kursrs)

If I remove this line from manifest.webapp:

```
"type": "privileged",
```

the application loads to WebIDE and work fine.

Unfortunately I can not submit it to Firefox marketplace like that because I need systemXHR.

If I try to load the application as is, with `"type": "privileged"`, to WebIDE I just get the Loading screen and application hangs.

Any idea what is the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error: call to Function() blocked by CSP underscore-1.8.3.min.js:5:15107

Comment: Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource: An attempt to call JavaScript from a string (by calling a function like eval) has been blocked underscore-1.8.3.min.js:5:0

Comment: this two things blocked from execution

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please tell me how you determine that so I can do it myself in the future?

Comment: after run app in web ide go the file then debug app then console. there you can find error if exists